# Setting different strings within a title for multiple graphs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I want to have a title such as "**Japan** IP firms patent filings: mean=834.41, standard deviation=534.56 with the bolded string changing for the different figures.
The mean and standard deviation are already changing using this code:

```
title = "Japan IP firms patent filings: mu =%.2f, std = %.2f"%(mu,std)
```

But I want to string together/concatenate the list 'name' below to the above title for every normal distribution figure:

```
names=[Japan, UK, USA, Uruguay, Brazil,Mexico,Costa Rica]
```

This is the code in the for loop i have so far

```
for item in totalIPs:

    mu=statistics.mean(item)
    std=statistics.stdev(item)

    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)

    fitted_pdf=ss.norm.pdf(x,mu, std)

    plt.figure()

    plt.xlabel('Distribution of patents by IP firms',fontsize=12)

    plt.ylabel('Frequency of firms of each patents',fontsize=12)

    plt.hist(x, bins=10,normed=True, alpha=0.6, edgecolor='black', color = 'g')

    plt.plot(x, fitted_pdf, 'K', linewidth=2)
        title = "Japan IP firms patent filings: mu =%.2f, std = %.2f"%(mu,std)
    plt.title(title)
```

I think I have to use the matplotlib.Axes method set_title to do this but I am not sure how to combine it with the code i have already for the '`title`'

Comment: if you build the totalIPs as a dict where key would be name of country and value would be the values in current implementation's totalIPs. And then just iterating over the dict will give you country name as well as totalIPs.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` you can iterate over your `names` at the same time as `totalIPs`, and then you can use string formatting to include that `name` in your `title` string:

```
names = ['Japan', 'UK', 'USA', 'Uruguay', 'Brazil', 'Mexico', 'Costa Rica']

for item, name in zip(totalIPs, names):

    mu=statistics.mean(item)
    std=statistics.stdev(item)

    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    x=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)

    fitted_pdf=ss.norm.pdf(x,mu, std)

    plt.figure()

    plt.xlabel('Distribution of patents by IP firms',fontsize=12)

    plt.ylabel('Frequency of firms of each patents',fontsize=12)

    plt.hist(x, bins=10,normed=True, alpha=0.6, edgecolor='black', color = 'g')

    plt.plot(x, fitted_pdf, 'K', linewidth=2)

    title = "{} IP firms patent filings: mu ={:.2f}, std = {:.2f}".format(name, mu, std)
    plt.title(title)
```